# A nice platform for selling PDF books like Google Play. Any suggestions?

Tags: pdf, google-play-books

I'm an author who are currently selling books on Google Play. The service works really good and has a wide support for mobile devices etc. The huge downside is its limitations when it comes to territory. It's only available in like 30 countries.

I have people in Israel, Nepal and other countries where Google Play don't reside and probably won't be for a while. So I'm looking for an alternative platform that does not have this limitation. However, I still have some requirements:

- **Prohibit download of the PDF** - This is to protect it from being spread outside of the platform. It has happen before when I even had DRM support turned off on Amazon. Writing 700 pages trying to make a living out of it kinda sucks when someone simply spreads it for free.
- **HTML5 or Mobile App support** - Since most of the readers will be using iPads and what not.
- **The book needs to be sold on that platform or a third party**
- **Need to use PDF.**

Is there any good platform for this except Google Books? I have searched like hell but all I have found is sites that provides the user with a download link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note html5 and pdf are rather different formats.

Comment: I think Philip means that the store offers a web and/or app interface for reading the PDF ebook.

Comment: I've sold ebooks in 52 countries on Google Play since 2012, and there is something like 79 countries generally available (many Middle Eastern countries are not generally available, but some publishers do have access). I'm not sure why one would think there are only 30 countries in Google Play. It is the widest marketplace for books that I am aware of, and competes well with Apple (51 countries), and Kobo. Also, they have encrypted/drm for their platform. They support their apps and the web, and as you know the publisher/author submits epub (or pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at Amazon's [Kindle Direct Publishing](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/)? It says Kindle in the name, but it is also possible to send the ebooks to tablets or smart phones and read them on there.

Comment: Kindle Direct Publishing does not support pdf or even epub files.

Comment: You can upload epub to Kindle Direct Publishing, and Amazon will convert to its various proprietary formats for customers' specific devices. KDP won't accept or sell PDF though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Scribd, if you go through one of their content partners, as described at https://support.scribd.com/hc/en-us/articles/210134806-My-Books-on-Scribd.