# How to distribute self-published pdf widely as we know from eBooks in epub format?

Tags: independent-publishing

When selfpublishing you either submit your creation as epub OR it's converted into epub by a distributor, a dedicated publishing company, who finally distrubutes it to online shops like amazon, book shops, google play etc.

In this respect the distributor does a bit of marketing the eBook in dpub format.

Do we have similar distributors for pdf beyond the one(s) given here: [A nice platform for selling PDF books like Google Play. Any suggestions?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/a-nice-platform-for-selling-pdf-books-like-google-play-any-suggestions) ? Submit as pdf, distribute widely as pdf.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to sell them on payhip. Easy to set up, no cost, special digital watermarking for PDFs, high earnings,  NO DRM. (A similar solution is gumroad, but I prefer payhip).

The challenge -- and it's a gigantic one -- is persuading people to buy digital content from a platform people are unfamiliar with.  For the record, none of the major vendors (like Amazon, Apple, Google Play) accept PDFs for sale -- although Kindle has a way to export pdf into some fixed layout format.

I realize that some content is much harder to produce for epub, but that is the international standard for ebooks -- it's designed especially for multiple sizes of displays. Also, epubs can be easily converted to PDF (using Calibre and other tools).